# Importing single excel file with multiple sheets to multiple datagridviews in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using below code to importing an excel sheet to DataGridView in VB.net. In below code excel file with sheet name "PA" importing to related datagridview named dgvPA. But in same Excel i have two more tab named HP and MP and i'd like to import them in same instance with pa but i don't know how to implement that.

```
Public Shared Sub ImportAll(ByVal dgvPA As DataGridView, ByVal dgvHP As DataGridView, ByVal dgvMP As DataGridView)
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog With {
        .Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx",
        .Title = "Import Model Info Sheet"
    }
    Try
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            filepath = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName)
            Globals.ModelInfoSheet = filepath
        End If
        dgvPA.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Globals.ModelInfoSheet & "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_pa & "$]", MyConnection)
        Dim DtSet As DataTable
        DtSet = New DataTable
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        dgvPA.DataSource = DtSet
        MyConnection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("File successfully imported")
        frmMain.tabBuildLocal.SelectedTab = frmMain.tabBuildImportList

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

For HP;

```
    `MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_hp & "$]", MyConnection)` and i'd like to import it in dgvHP
```

and for MP;
        `MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_mp & "$]", MyConnection)` and i'd like to import it in dgvMP

How can i implement these additional tabs with the same instance of ImportAll. When i call the ImportAll procedure i'd like to fill datagridviews at once otherwise i should create new procedures and import them seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary which the key is the sheet name, and the value the right DataGridView, and iterate it, example:

```
Public Shared Sub ImportAll(ByVal dgvPA As DataGridView, ByVal dgvHP As DataGridView, ByVal dgvMP As DataGridView)
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog With {
        .Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx",
        .Title = "Import Model Info Sheet"
    }
    Try
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            filepath = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName)
            Globals.ModelInfoSheet = filepath
        End If
        dgvPA.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Globals.ModelInfoSheet & "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

        Dim tables = New Dictionary(Of String, DataGridView) From {
            {My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_pa, dgvPA},
            {My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_hp, dgvHP},
            {My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_mp, dgvMP}
        }

        For Each item In tables
            Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & item.Key & "$]", MyConnection)
            Dim DtSet As DataTable
            DtSet = New DataTable
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            item.Value.DataSource = DtSet
        Next


        MyConnection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("File successfully imported")
        frmMain.tabBuildLocal.SelectedTab = frmMain.tabBuildImportList

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great:) Also one off topic question i wonder should i use & item.Key & or + item.Key +